# How to add search place image in google map marker in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

My Concept is that, when search place in google map this place image is add in marker, marker is image view, i am use serch location code from this link http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-geocoding-showing-user-input-location-on-google-map-android-api-v2/
and in this code use owen marker that is image view. so how i can add image

public class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask>{

```
    @Override
    protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
        // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        respo=myServiceToHttp.makeServiceCall("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query="+addresses+"&key=Your Server KEy", MyServiceToHttp.GET);
        System.out.println("MyGeocoderTask.doInBackground()------Image---->"+respo);

        try {

            String placeid=null;

            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(respo);

            JSONArray array=jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            //System.out.println("GeocoderTask.doInBackground()---------->"+array);

            for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++) {

                JSONObject jsonObject2= array.getJSONObject(j);

                placeid=jsonObject2.getString("place_id");

                System.out.println("GeocoderTask.doInBackground()------PlaceID-->"+placeid);

                respo2=myServiceToHttp.makeServiceCall("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid="+placeid+"&key=Your Server KEy", MyServiceToHttp.GET);

                System.out.println("Response2-->>>>" +respo2);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }



        try {


            // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0],4);


        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return addresses;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {

        if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Clears all the existing markers on the map
        googleMap.clear();

        // Adding Markers on Google Map for each matching address
        for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){


            Address address  = (Address) addresses.get(i);

            // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
            latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());


             String addressText = String.format("%s, %s, %s,%s",
                       address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(1) : "",
                       address.getThoroughfare(),
                        // Locality is usually a city
                        address.getLocality(),
                        // The country of the address
                        address.getCountryName());

            marker = new MarkerOptions();
            marker.position(latLng);
            marker.title(addressText);


            //googleMap.addMarker(marker);

            // Locate the first location
            if(i==0)
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details

Comment: Check this as well http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/custom-marker-icon-for-google-maps-android-api-v2/

Comment: This is my way respo is exicute and show address response but its show always canda area response

Answer (score 0):

Just try this :

```
 // Uses a custom icon.
    mIndia = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(SYDNEY)
        .title("Sydney")
        .snippet("Population: 4,627,300")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));

As this just replaces the marker with an image you might want to use a Canvas to draw more complex and fancier stuff:

Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(80, 80, conf);
Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(bmp);

// paint defines the text color,
// stroke width, size
Paint color = new Paint();
color.setTextSize(35);
color.setColor(Color.BLACK);

//modify canvas
canvas1.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    R.drawable.user_picture_image), 0,0, color);
canvas1.drawText("User Name!", 30, 40, color);

//add marker to Map
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(USER_POSITION)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp))
    // Specifies the anchor to be at a particular point in the marker image.
    .anchor(0.5f, 1));
```

Comment: tnx.......but I am use serch place code from this linkhttp://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-geocoding-showing-user-input-location-on-google-map-android-api-v2/....